# copy/move/conversion semantic when derived object was bound to base class reference?

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I want to understand C++ as much as I can. If there is a base class `B` and a derived class `D`. `D d;` instantiate a derived object.

1. `B & rb = d;`, `rb` refers to derived object `d`. This does **NOT** instantiate a new object of base class. So which memory part does `rb` refer to?
2. `B newb = d;`, this will call will call the **copy constructor** of base class. Object `d` will first be bound to the parameter type `const B&`, and then a new object of base class is instantiated.
3. `B newbb(static_cast<B>(d));`, what will be accomplished in this statement?

The three statements above are my own way to understand the `copy/move/conversion` of objects. But they really confuses me. I cannot find an effective and clear way to interpret the codes, though I have read the corresponding part of **C++11 standard**.

I hope answers to explain the three statements with code quotation. What happened during the object copy/move/conversion.

---

Help! Hope answers from you guys!!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Would you help clarify this question Many thx.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I need your help on this.

Comment: If you are looking for help on understanding my answer, I'm willing to help with any questions. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 0):

In general, these should all be copy operations, sometimes with conversions first. I'll cover move operations below.

Part 1:
The language that I'm about to use might differ from the standard a little bit, but I would tend to think of `rb` as referring to the whole object `d`. The reason I say that is that when I'm doing something like this, `D` almost always has a least one virtual function, and any virtual function called through `rb` will run the version from `D`, not `B`. For example, if we have:

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual int get_value() { return 10; }
};

class D: public B
{
public:
    virtual int get_value() { return 20; }
};
```

Then `rb.get_value()` will return 20, not 10 like you might be thinking.

Part 2:
This is actually something that you almost never want to do. What happens here is that the `d` is converted to a `B` by a process called "slicing", which discards the part that was unique to `D` and leaves only the `B` part, which is then copied to create `newb`. This might sound useful, but in practice you probably want to either create a complete copy of `d` rather than a partial one, or you don't want to create a copy at all and instead want to use a pointer or reference to `d`.

If you want to create a complete copy, you would probably want a virtual function to do the copy, like this:

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual B *clone()
    {
        return new B(*this);
    }
};

class D: public B
{
public:
    virtual B *clone()
    {
        return new D(*this);
    }
};
```

Part 3:
This is essentially the same as Part 2 - the presence of the `static_cast` just makes the slicing explicit rather than something that the compiler does automatically. Again, this is probably not something you will want to do very often.

---

Depending on context, expressions like the ones you are using might become move operations instead. For example, if `d` were about to be destroyed, the compiler might recognize that and call a move function instead of a copy, since moving is generally more efficient. For example:

```
B foo()
{
    D d;
    return d;
}
```

In C++11, the return-statement might call the move constructor (if it exists) rather than the copy constructor to create the return value. That said, the effect should be pretty similar - the slicing that happens in Parts 2 and 3 would happen whichever of the two constructors was called.